# What could possibly cause getenv to fail when the variable is present in .env file?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `.env` file containing `SOME_IP=127.0.0.1:8080`. In a Laravel controller for a certain request I call `$foo = getenv('SOME_IP');`. About 90% of the time it works fine, I get the string and proceed. But the other 10% of times, `getenv` returns `false`, even though the variable is clearly in the `.env` file. What could be causing this?

Alternatively, Laravel's `env` returns `null`.

*Observed with `vlucas/phpdotenv` `v2.6.4`.*

Comment: why not use laravel function: env("SOME_IP");

Comment: I tried with `env` as well, it has the same exact problem.

Comment: Try to restart server once, do `php artisan optimize:clear`, check your variable name properly.

Comment: did you try php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:clear

Comment: Just tried `cache:clear` and `config:clear` and unfortunately it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because of [caching the config](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching).
It is better to load your env variable in a config file and then retrieve it from the config.
For example you can create a file with the name 'ips' in config directory like this:

```
<?php
return ['someIp' => env('SOME_IP')];
```

and then use

```
$foo = config('ips.someIp')
```