# docker-compose environment property not available in php built-in web server

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

To demonstrating the issue, I setup a sample laravel app in a dockerfile which uses php built-in server:

```
FROM composer:latest

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN composer create-project laravel/laravel . --no-dev

RUN mv ./.env.example .env

RUN php artisan key:generate

RUN echo "<?php Route::get('test', fn() => dump(getenv('MY_ENV')));" > routes/api.php

CMD php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

As you can see i added a route to simply dump the `MY_ENV` variable which defined in `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"

services: 
  laravel:
    build: .
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      MY_ENV: 123
```

And: `docker compose up -d` then head over to `localhost:8000/api/test`.

As you can see `getenv` return false but i expected it to be `123`

The interesting part is, When i use laravel tinker the variable is available :

[image]

But this variable is not available in the actual app, What would be the problem here?

Comment: Maybe change the way you get the values to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67467436/1213708

Comment: The `env` function does not work either

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the docker compose environment it's not for build the image.

If you want to pass the argument to the dockerfile throught the docker-cmpose.yml you need to use this

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services: 
  laravel:
    build: .
      args:
        MY_ENV: 123
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      MY_ENV: 123
```

And in the dockerfile you setup the `ARG MY_ENV` to use it, like this:

```
ARG MY_ENV
FROM composer:latest

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN composer create-project laravel/laravel . --no-dev

RUN mv ./.env.example .env

RUN php artisan key:generate

RUN echo "<?php Route::get('test', fn() => dump($buildno));" > routes/api.php

CMD php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Reference: [How to define build args in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734271/how-to-define-build-args-in-docker-compose)

Comment: Thanks, But the weird issue is, When i use ngnix as web server, It read the `environment` variables.

Comment: ARG is fine, But i need to use ENV variables because i need to override .env variables file

Comment: @Mwthreex When you said that ngnix it read the environment, is it after the build of image?
Because what I think is that you can't using env during building image, because it's docker and not the ngnix server running.

Comment: the `CMD` instructor is not execute in the build time, Doesn't it ? Because i boot up web server with CMD in last line of dockerfile.

Comment: @Mwthreex from the documentation of docker `Do not confuse RUN with CMD. RUN actually runs a command and commits the result; CMD does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the intended command for the image.`
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

So the server isn't running until the image is created, then you can access to env file.